# Differences between Convolutional Neural Network architectures

Tags: architecture, neural-network, conv-neural-network

What are the differences between CNN architectures? (AlexNet, ConvNet, ResNet, etc...)

How can I tell them apart?

Because most of the CNNs I encounter on the internet, to me are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional Neural Networks are special types of Neural Networks that use special "Convolution" layers - different architectures, such as AlexNet, VGGNet, ResNet, etc., use different amounts of layers, filter sizes, number of filters, etc.

However, usually, different types of architectures have their own distinct fingerprint. For example:

- VGGNet has its signature pattern (Conv-Conv-Conv-Pool)
- Inception has the Inception Modules, which allow the model to be heavily optimized.
- ResNet has Residual connections, which allow the model to be much deeper, without sacrificing on accuracy.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. So let's say I have the following module: `Conv. Layer -> Pooling -> ReLU -> Fully Connect Lyper -> Fully Connect Layer`, what would be the architecture of this network? And I could repeat after ReLU: `Conv. Layer -> Pooling -> ReLU` as many times as I want.

Comment: Well, that would be your own model - unless someone else has built the same type of model as you, and named it. But, as far as I'm aware, this model isn't a standard of any sort. You can call it whatever you'd like - it's like a generic CNN.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful.